# C# static "this"

Tags: c#, static, this

Is there a way in a C# static method to refer to the Type the method is defined in?

In an instance method you can determine the type by:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Type type = this.GetType();
}
```

how would it look like in a static method?

```
public static void Bar()
{
    Type type = ....?
}
```

**Update: Sorry, clarification needed:** I know the `typeof(...)` feature. I'm looking for a keyword or code that gives me the Type without explicitly referencing the class name.

**Update:** Besides Developer Art's answer, which does exactly what I was looking for, is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you going to do with this `Type` object once you've got it?

Comment: What are the intention behind the code? What the hell are you using the type information for in a static method anyway?

Comment: @Yves: This has nothing to do with hell. I simply need the Type object to pass it as a parameter to a given method. Why shouldn't a Type be used in a static method? Type is not a state nor is it in any other way specific to an instance.

Comment: @AakashM: Of course at design time I know the type and can reference it explicitely, but it's for code that I copy-paste or move a lot and still it should always refer to the type that encloses it. (To be more precise, for log4net logging statements, but I'm also just curious generally.)

Comment: If it's for log4net then your question becomes close to being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852923/class-decorator-to-declare-static-member-e-g-for-log4net :)

Comment: @AakashM: Very interesting link! But it's not a duplicate because what I've just described is my *intention* behind my question, but it's not my question. ;-)

Comment: I think this is a very interesting problem. My interest in will have to do with when a derived class calls a static method and you want to get a hold of the Type for that derived class.  In an instance method a simple this.GetType() will give you what you want.  But in a static method, I am not sure there is a clear way of achieving the same.  There is some interesting talk in the plans for C#7 but I am not sure how this will pan out.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static void Bar()
{
  Type type = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
}
```

Edit: updated to correct error - DeclaringType is a property.

Comment: Although this method is generic it is more costly than a simple, static 'typeof (ClassName)'.

Comment: The author is obviously interested in getting the type without specifying its name explicitly.

Comment: Does this require a `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` decoration to prevent getting the wrong method?

Comment: I don't think so. This might only be needed if you used the GetFrame method.

Comment: @Developer Art: Exactly, that's what I'm interested in. This solution looks appropriate and safe, saver than the StackTrace approach. Does that mean that there is no simpler way? No keyword, e.g.?

Comment: Interesting, but is requires Reflection permission. It is costly not only on performance but also on security.  Both may not be an issue at all in many situations, but it's good to remain aware of what prevents generality.  In my case I ended up duplicating the class name.  Duplicating is generally bad but everything is compromise, isn't it ?

Comment: @chiccodoro Nowadays if you really wanted to you could add a static alias directive like: `using Self = <your_class_name>;`, and then get the type using `typeof(Self)`.

Answer (score 13):

```
public class Foo {
   public static void Bar() {
      Type type = typeof(Foo);
   }
}
```

You could also use the stacktrace

```
public class Foo {
   public static void Bar() {
        Type type = new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
   }
}
```

Comment: @m0sa - I have seen instances where the optimizer omits entries from the stack trace, and if that happens the second method here will not work.  See here for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/03/20/399287.aspx

Comment: Everything was clearly identified on the right... var isn't abused if it's clear in it's intentions. 4 lines instead of 1 might be considered abuse... but var abuse? hardly

Comment: @m0sa - I found out the hard way when someone in my team was using this to identify a type this way. Worked in Debug but not Release.

Answer (score 4):

```
class ClassA
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
        Type t = typeof(ClassA);
    }
}
```

Captain Obvious, I know.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `typeof`?

```
public class Foo
{
  public static void Bar()
  {
    Type type = typeof(Foo);
  }
}
```

Or like Developer Art suggested it, you could do it using reflection, but it will be slower.

```
using System.Reflection;
public class Foo
{
  public static void Bar()
  {
    Type type = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
 Type t = typeof ( Program );
```

A very unusual way would be to use a StackTrace, taking the Type of the last frame...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit convoluted, but I think you could also go the route of a singleton-type pattern

```
public class Foo
{
    private static Foo _Instance = new Foo();
    public static Type Bar()
    {
        return _Instance.GetType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, if I created a private static field which refers explicitly to the enclosing type, then I'd rather use `private static Type _thisType = typeof(Foo);`

Comment: That works too :) I was just throwing some alternative methods out there.   If the scenerio ever came up again where you needed a static version of "this", then this approach gives you that....If the type is all you'll ever need, than any of these approaches gives you that pretty well.

Comment: Hi Steven, sorry, I didn't read your code well enough and didn't realize that your Bar() method exactly does that, just providing the Type. I though that was "my" static method that *needs* the type.

Comment: Still my "proposal" would be even simpler. A one-liner good to copy and paste. If you want you can incorporate it in your answer as a 2nd variant.

Comment: @chiccodoro - I don't think I explained myself very clearly, so I apologize if I was vague. I don't disagree that what you're suggesting is simpler, and if easy access to the Type is all you'll ever need, then the static '_Instance' is probably overkill. I was just throwing this out there based on the title of the question. *if* you ever needed the static equivalent of a "this" for some other reason, then having something like a static _Instance provides you with that...